# Trying to run a test using Docker-compose container with a Firefox Browser Got an error message

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Trying to run a test in docker-compose as I want to change the standard electron browser to firefox

I used the following command:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --browser firefox
```

I suspect I made a school boy error as I got the following message.  I got the following message.  How do I fix this?

```
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
flag.

If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the
`--force-recreate` flag.

Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [--] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
    --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
    --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
                               and image haven't changed.
    --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
                               Incompatible with --no-recreate.
    --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
                               them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
    --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
    --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
    --build                    Build images before starting containers.
    --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was
jacquelinegeorge@Jacquelines-MacBook-Air CypressDocker % docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --browser firefox
Builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service.

Unless they are already running, this command also starts any linked services.

The `docker-compose up` command aggregates the output of each container. When
the command exits, all containers are stopped. Running `docker-compose up -d`
starts the containers in the background and leaves them running.

If there are existing containers for a service, and the service's configuration
or image was changed after the container's creation, `docker-compose up` picks
up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted
volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the `--no-recreate`
flag.

If you want to force Compose to stop and recreate all containers, use the
`--force-recreate` flag.

Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [--] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                               print new container names. Incompatible with
                               --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
    --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
    --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
                               and image haven't changed.
    --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
                               Incompatible with --no-recreate.
    --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
                               them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
    --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
    --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
    --build                    Build images before starting containers.
    --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was
                               stopped. Incompatible with -d.
    --attach-dependencies      Attach to dependent containers.
    -t, --timeout TIMEOUT      Use this timeout in seconds for container
                               shutdown when attached or when containers are
                               already running. (default: 10)
    -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
                               data from the previous containers.
    --remove-orphans           Remove containers for services not defined
                               in the Compose file.
    --exit-code-from SERVICE   Return the exit code of the selected service
                               container. Implies --abort-on-container-exit.
    --scale SERVICE=NUM        Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the
                               `scale` setting in the Compose file if present.
    --no-log-prefix            Don't print prefix in logs.
```

Comment: Are you executing that command in the directory where the docker-compose.yml is at? Also try removing `-f docker-compose.yml` from the command

Comment: yes. I am executing the command the directory.  I will modify the question

Comment: You're providing the `--browser` argument to `docker compose up` and docker is saying "I don't understand this."  Did you mean `docker compose up firefox --browser`?

Comment: @kthompso Yes.  Let me give that suggestion a try.

Comment: `--browser` isn't an option to [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/).  Is this an option to a specific container? What did you want it to do?

Comment: @DavidMaze  I want to run a specific container that will use Firefox  or a container that will use Chrome as a browser to run my test